# Ubuntu in Hyper-V I/O issues

Tags: server, virtualization, hyper-v

I have anecdotal information from a colleague about performance issues running Ubuntu Server in a Hyper-V environment and I wanted to find out if there was any truth to it.  Has anyone had any experience running Ubuntu Server in Hyper-V and are there any tricks to getting good hard drive performance?

Answer (score 1):

You might do better and not have to shell out a bunch of cash to use Ubuntu and qemu-kvm or virtualbox as the host instead of Microsoft's proprietary OS and VM.

Comment: Yes, but we are going to have an MS stack anyway, and I was wanting consolidation.  We are an MS partner, and Hyper-V is 'free' (I know, don't laugh!) when you buy the OS.